# Why does TableCloumn<S,T> take 2 Elements?

Tags: javafx

The JavaDoc says:

```
Type Parameters:
    S - The type of the TableView generic type (i.e. S == TableView<S>)
    T - The type of the content in all cells in this TableColumn.
```

What does "generic type" mean in this context? If the content is a String, the generic type would also be a string, would it not?

I'm trying to compile the  following code taking a String:

```
TableColumn col = new TableColumn<?, String>();

public void append(String str) {
  col.add(str);
}
```

Why am I not able to do this?

Comment: You want to use this TableColumn inside a TableView, use the generic Type of the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

- S is your domain object
- T is a value of the domain object you want to
  show in that column.

Please have a look at the Javadoc for these kind of questions:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html